# How can I get the Path value in this Json?

Tags: powershell

I have a Json which is similar to this sample here

```
{
    "vaults": {
        "43371adf": {
            "path": "C:\\Users\\user23\\Documents\\Mango Vault",
            "ts": 16767
        },
        "54a80cfadc691ec4": {
            "path": "C:\\Users\\user23\\Documents\\Apple Vault",
            "ts": 166576
        },
        "af524734": {
            "path": "C:\\Users\\user23\\Documents\\Orange Vault",
            "ts": 166985
        },
        "40290aab5": {
            "path": "C:\\Users\\user23\\Documents\\Banana Vault",
            "ts": 167293,
            "open": true
        }
    },
    "frame": "hidden"
}
```

I am interested in retrieving the values for the keys `Path`. Some things I tried are:

```
$vaultsIndex = Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\sample.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
$vaultsIndex.vaults
$vaultsIndex.vaults | foreach {$_.where -eq 'path'}  #Returns 'False'
$vaultsIndex.vaults.where -eq 'path'                 #Also Returns 'False'
```

The only thing that works is `$vaultsIndex.vaults.43371adf` which I cant automate at all, I really need to just be all to get all the paths in a generic way.

The searches I performed just pointed me to this `$_.where()` method. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access an object's Properties by calling [`.PSObject.Properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject.properties?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0) over said object. Since you're interested only in the `path` of each object in `vault`, we can call the [`.Value` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psmemberinfo.value?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0#system-management-automation-psmemberinfo-value) of the property collection to access them and from there call `.path` over each object to get the values. This is done via [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.2):

```
$json.vaults.PSObject.Properties.Value.path
```